# Initialize C++ input/output streams for programming in assembly

Tags: nasm

Here is my full source code for a Win32 C++ program fully writen in NASM:
http://devel.archefire.org/tmp/01_00.cpp.zip

I want to interface with the C++ functions like the ones from Windows (MSVCIRT.DLL).

I have tried to run a program like this to print a string:

```
#include <iostream.h>
void main()
{
     cout <<"Welcome to Programming in C++";
}
```

When I translate it to NASM, cout doesn't print anything:

     `push wideword main_printf_str_1
     mov widecx,?cout@@3Vostream_withassign@@A@MSVCIRT.DLL
     call wideword[??6ostream@@QAEAAV0@PBD@Z@MSVCIRT.DLL]`

So I guess that I need to do initializations for input/output streams and maybe standard "base" classes similar to what is done when initializing stdin,stdout,stderr with __p_iob from MSVCRT.DLL.

What C++ functions do I need to call to get an initialized cout that would print when calling ostream in assembly, or why doesn't the assembly above print anything, as if cout was invalid?

Comment: Why would you even do that in plain assembly language?

Comment: `std::cout` is already there. Just use `stream.write` if you want to get raw output.

Comment: I need to learn to interface the C++ environment from plain assembly for better portability, to strip unused code, to understand the actual structure of C++ code using different implementatons (GCC, MSVC, Open Watcom, etc.). It's just a matter of knowing how to initialize default streams and other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://devel.archefire.org/tmp/01_00.cpp.zip

I have finally fixed the problem.

For being able to output with `cout << "";`, I found that The following 2 `MSVCIRT.DLL` references need to be called:

```
push wideword main_printf_str_1
mov widecx,[?cout@@3Vostream_withassign@@A@MSVCIRT.DLL]
call wideword[??6ostream@@QAEAAV0@PBD@Z@MSVCIRT.DLL]
```

Then, before ending the program we need to call `exit(int );` from `MSVCRT.DLL`. That will flush the output for `cout`.

Probably formal flushing could be used, but Visual C++ 6.0 produces code that ends with a call to `exit(int )` after returning from `main()` to force things like this final flush, and doesn't explicitly flush anything after the `cout << "";`.